# JWT - Necessity of storing refresh token expiration in DB alongside token

Tags: express, http, cookies, jwt

I'm implementing a back-end system that uses JWT authentication with access and refresh tokens. I have decided I will store the user's refresh token in MySQL DB adjacent to other user-related info (i.e., inside the USERS relation).

In my research on JWT, access, and refresh tokens, I have read some suggestions that in storing a refresh token in a DB, one ought to store the expiration date as well.

At first, this seems logical and reasonable to me. However, after thinking about it some more, I feel as though it may be unnecessary to do so.

Referencing the [jsonwebtoken API docs](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme), if the server wants to check whether or not a user-provided token has expired, one could simply:

1. acquire the token (either from the DB or from the user-provided request cookies)
2. call `jwt.verify(token)` within a `try-catch`

if the token was *indeed* expired, calling the aforementioned function should throw a `TokenExpiredError`, according to the jwt docs, that could then be caught and dealt with accordingly.

Does this seem right? If so, why would anyone suggest or want to store a JWT token's expiration date alongside the token in a DB?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there's no need to store the expiration date in the database.
When a user wants to get a new access token, the first thing you would check is that the refresh token is valid and not expired and then you would check if it's in the database and not revoked. The expired case can be identifed by `TokenExpiredError` and be handled accordingly just as you mentioned.

EDIT : I can think of one case where storing expiration date might be useful.

If you want to support multi logins, then you would store multiple refresh tokens for the same user.

What if a user logs in 10 times in incognito mode or from 10 browsers ?
Then you would have refresh tokens sitting in your db that would go unused until removed

What you can do is, set up a routine maintenance that deletes old tokens. One way to do that is to use expiration date as the filter to determine what tokens should be deleted. If all your refresh tokens has a fixed duration of validity then another way would be to use the creation date to filter tokens older than that duration and delete them

Note : Refresh tokens should not be stored in plain text as its sensitive data, it should be hashed or encrypted. Even if someone do store it in plain text and wants to get the expiration date by decoding each token that would be very inefficient anyway